# Google Maps Geolocation refreshes page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, apache-cordova

I am trying to create a google map. This map should stay centered and never move. I am creating live tracking, but I am having issues with the tracking. Every couple of seconds the tracking feature refreshes the page every couple of seconds.

```
    .controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicLoading, $compile, $ionicPopup, $cordovaGeolocation) {

$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
var onSuccess = function(position) {


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var CSUS_CENTER = (38.55914, -121.423473);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: CSUS_CENTER,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoomControl: true,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions);

            //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
            var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
            var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: compiled[0]
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Sac State'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            $scope.map = map;
            $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

});
```

So, my issues are that the map recenters every time it refreshes, and I want to keep it centred at the original latitude and longitude. Then the other issue is that the page keeps freshing

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to get the position once, use [getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition), not [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition)

Comment: changing watchPoistion to getCurrentPosition does stop it from refreshing but i need it too contentiously track me